# "No current record" error when aggregate with Boolean field in MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This query return "No current record" error. [use_Override1] is Boolean. Instead if I define [use_Override1] as string with values "TRUE" or "FALSE" it works. Can somebody tell me on why?

```
SELECT  '*' AS Sector, tbl.blkName AS Sector2, Sub2.use_Override1
FROM( (dbSecurityAllocation AS tbl 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM dbHoldings WHERE dbHoldings.Code_BB='SQECR' AND DataDiEstrazione='30/11/2020') AS Sub1 
ON tbl.isin=Sub1.isin) 
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT * FROM dbAggregateAlloc WHERE Code_BB='SQECR' AND fldName='FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC')  AS Sub2 
ON Sub2.blkName=tbl.blkName)
GROUP BY  tbl.blkName,Sub2.use_Override1
```

Comment: Don't tag spam. If you are using Microsoft Access tag that, and just that, not random other unrelated products. MySQL isn't even made by the same company as Access and SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you have asterisk within apostrophes with an alias name? This just returns a field named Sector with an asterisk character. Is DataDiEstrazione a date/time or text field? You try grouping on use_Override1 as a yes/no field and it fails but as a text field it works? I tested this and have no problem with a yes/no field in GROUP BY. Then I tested your syntax with alias names and that also works. Since you don't have any aggregate calcs, maybe should use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY. No fields from Sub1 are pulled into outer query so why include it? Edit q to show data and desired output.

Comment: I need a column of asterisks as output. DataDiEstrazione is a text field. The idea is to have an aggregate calcs clolumn, but I was trying to find a reason for the error first

Comment: June7, the error was that tbl.blkName has a value that in not in Sub2.blkName (n/c for not classified). I discovered after you said that tested the query without problem. Still cannot figure out why it works with string fields and not with boolean.